# how to set a child div as draggable but not the parent

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to dynamically create divs which will then be draggable. I found though, that the entire parent div moves along with it. If I create multiple child divs, they also move together with the parent. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "button#new-child" )
        .button()
        .click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#creation-box").append("<div class='draggable  ui-widget-content'><p>Drag me around</p></div>").draggable();

        });
});
```

and the html

```
<body>
<div id="toolbar">
<div class="header"> <h3>Toolbar</h3></div>
<button id="new-child">New Child</button>
</div>

<div id="creation-box">
<div class="header"><h3>Creation Box</h3></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you set the parent as draggable. Set your new element as draggable after creation only.

BTW, `.append()` doesn't have callback, so just add the `.draggable` after element creation.

```
$(function() {
    $( "button#new-child" )
        .button()
        .click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#creation-box").append("<div id='new-element-with-unique-id' class='draggable ui-widget-content'><p>Drag me around</p></div>");

            $("#new-element-with-unique-id").draggable();

        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that, that fixed the problem. I made the unique id name with a counter variable.